# group by and count using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a result class:

```
public class Ville
{
    public int Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a `list<AnnonceRecherche>`, I need to make query on this list that group by `AnnonceRecherche.CodeInsee` and count items in this group, order descending and map `Ville.Nombre=count()` and`vilee.name=AnnonceRecherche.Name` and `ville.id=AnnonceRecherche.CodeInsee`

I start my query like this, but id don't find how to map Name:

```
   var query = from annonce in newresults
            group annonce by annonce.Id
            into grouping
            select new Ville {id = grouping.Key, Nombre = grouping.Count() , Name =};
```

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried: `Name = grouping.annonce.Name`?

Comment: You can't just group on `annonce.Id` and select the `Name`, because these names could differ per `annonce.Id`. Biside, the name `Id` assumes that is should be unique. It's useless to group on something unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're grouping by a unique column, you can always add a second column to that if its values are also unique to that first column:

```
var query = (from annonce in newresults
            group annonce by new { annonce.Id, annonce.Name }
            into grouping
            select new Ville 
            {
                 ID = grouping.Key.Id, 
                 Name = grouping.Key.Name, 
                 Nombre = grouping.Count() 
            }).OrderByDescending(x=> x.Nombre);
```

Comment: OP wants to group only by `AnnonceRecherche.CodeInsee`

Comment: On how can I order desc by groupin.count in the same query please?

Comment: I need only to grou by on one column also

Comment: @user1428798 Every `ID` has a unique `Name`, so it is safe to virtually group by the name.

Comment: So, grouping by `Id` and `Name`, should not be a problem. If the `Id` is also unique. If the `Id` is unique, you shouldn't group at all! And if multiple rows with the same `Id` has the same `Name`, you should normalize the datastructure.

Comment: @user1428798 Ordering added.